# CXF2.7.2 + Weblogic 12c + Java 1.7

Tags: cxf, java-7, weblogic12c, wss4j, xmlsec

There is an issue with running **CXF** application of **Weblogic 12c**. Exception is as following:

```
org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
```

The interesting here is that **DOMXMLSignatureFactory** extends **XMLSignatureFactory**. I've tried to debug and haven't found the cause. **XMLSec-1.5.3** code fails on following line:
 `XMLSignatureFactory fac = (XMLSignatureFactory)ps.newInstance(null);`

```
private static XMLSignatureFactory findInstance(String mechanismType,
    Provider provider) {

    if (provider == null) {
        provider = getProvider("XMLSignatureFactory", mechanismType);
    }
    Provider.Service ps = provider.getService("XMLSignatureFactory",
                                              mechanismType);
    if (ps == null) {
        throw new NoSuchMechanismException("Cannot find " + mechanismType +
                                           " mechanism type");
    }
    try {
        XMLSignatureFactory fac = (XMLSignatureFactory)ps.newInstance(null);
        fac.mechanismType = mechanismType;
        fac.provider = provider;
        return fac;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        throw new NoSuchMechanismException("Cannot find " + mechanismType +
                                           " mechanism type", nsae);
    }
}
```

Instantiated class "**org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory**" has declaration:

```
public final class DOMXMLSignatureFactory extends XMLSignatureFactory {
...
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Full stacktrace:

```
  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.crypto.dsig
.XMLSignatureFactory
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java
:195)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:98)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(Polic
yBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:165)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(Polic
yBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
        at $Proxy197.getProcessingEventDetails(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.paradase.top.green.hill.client.MiraclesPosterServlet.doPost(MiraclesPosterServlet.java:666)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:221)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.cryp
to.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory
        at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:202)
        at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:292)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.init(WSSecSignature.java:126)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.<init>(WSSecSignature.java:119)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.getSignatureBuilder(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:172
3)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignature(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:546)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java
:147)
        ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 1):

CXF uses WSS4J and wss4j version 1.6.7 has this bug.  Can you try upgrading to wss4j 1.6.9?  CXF 2.7.3 might pick this up for you. This update fixed the issue for me running in ServiceMix 4.5.0.